# Facebook C# SDK CanvasAction results in "HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed"

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

In my Facebook app I'm using the CanvasAction like so:

```
<div id="my-button" onclick="location.href='@Url.CanvasAction("Index", "Facebook")'">
```

which should invoke the Index method on FacebookController:

```
[CanvasAuthorize(Permissions = ExtendedPermissions)]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    .....
}
```

Currently configured the app so that that the host is localhost. 
This used to work but all of a sudden the response is "HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed".
I've changed my application so that it, as far as I can see, is identical to the "ASP.NET MVC3 Canvas Application without Facebook JavaScript" sample app included in the FB C# SDK which works.

It does work though if I append 'Index' to the address: http://apps.facebook.com/myapp/Facebook/Index/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved the code in the Index action method to a new action method and updated the first parameter in the CanvasAction call accordingly and now it works.
So instead of this:

```
<div id="my-button" onclick="location.href='@Url.CanvasAction("Index", "Facebook")'">
```

and

```
[CanvasAuthorize(Permissions = ExtendedPermissions)]
public ActionResult Index()
{
   .....
   return View();
}
```

this:

```
<div id="my-button" onclick="location.href='@Url.CanvasAction("PleaseWork", "Facebook")'">
```

and

```
[CanvasAuthorize(Permissions = ExtendedPermissions)]
public ActionResult PleaseWork()
{
   .....
   return View("Index");
}
```

I really have no idea why it doesn't work with the Index method.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an odd request, but check to see if your HTTPS version of your site is working correctly.  I've seen 405s when somethings wrong with the SSL cert.

Comment: It doesn't work with https since I'm running against localhost and I don't have a SSL cert.

Comment: You may have your account set to use https only, causing this to appear.  Try turning off use https only on your user's account and try again.

Comment: Do you mean the setting "Browse Facebook on a secure connection (https) when possible" under "Account Settings/Security/Secure Browsing"?`This is already turned off. Besides, the sample canvas app works fine using the same account which should rule out this option.